# How to customize Open in Terminal in Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop

Tags: 18.04, gnome, 20.04, nautilus, gnome-terminal

In Ubuntu 18.04 I had this setup such that I uninstalled gnome-terminal. By doing so, it uninstalls gnome-terminal as well as nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal. This also removes the context menu item Open in terminal (on the desktop view as well as the nautilus file explorer view)

I did this so that I could use a different terminal. However, I wanted the Open in terminal functionality back, and got it working using nautilus-python. Example: https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus-python/blob/master/examples/open-terminal.py

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, and attempted the same setup. However, it seems that the context menu on the desktop view of nautilus (is this even nautilus anymore ?) it does not remove the "Open in terminal" item. My hypothesis is that something else is adding it in there as when I changed the labels for "open in terminal" within open-terminal.py (file from above) it changes the context menus appropriately in Nautilus file manager view but not the desktop view.

I looked into `/var/log/syslog` and it keeps printing the line

```
Aug  5 02:24:00 xps-13-7390 gnome-shell[14400]: Unknown option: --working-directory
```

This is because normally if it was using gnome-terminal --working-directory is an arg that can be passed, however, the terminal that I am using does not accept this.

How do I make it so that I can either remove this, add a new context menu item, or fix the command that it is passing.

update:
Did some more research, it looks as if Nautilus has been removed from the GNOME desktop in Ubuntu 20.04 https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/gpw4h9/missing_new_document_context_menu_on_desktop/frp6j7h/ (This is pop_os which is System76's derivative of debian/Ubuntu but the finding seems to be the same)

Also, looked all over gsettings / dconf-editor and found nothing to control this stuff, however, things like certain desktop settings + wallpaper backgrounds are still controlled here under the `org.gnome.desktop` schema which leads me to believe it is still gnome desktop?

update2:
related? https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/158

update3:
Looks like it is using a gnome shell extension written here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons

The Open in Terminal is coming from here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons/-/blob/master/desktopGrid.js#L355

And the "--working-directory" is coming from here:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons/-/blob/master/desktopIconsUtil.js#L45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed by commenting out some code in the extension's source code and restarting gnome-shell.

Steps:

1. `cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano`
2. `vi desktopIconsUtil.js`
3. Comment out `--working-directory=${workdir}` like so: `` /*`--working-directory=${workdir}`*/ `` and save the file.
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> to "Run command" in Ubuntu.
5. Type `r`, press <kbd>enter</kbd>. GNOME shell should restart.

This should fix the issue. This can probably be customized more in this same location for other options your terminal of choice might have. Also, this might be desirable to fix in the extension's source, might look into submitting a pull request or something.

Comment: Also the change made here would be overwritten every time the package associated to the extension is updated.